How to simulate a beacon on one smartphone and to detect it on a second smartphone generating a automatic notification (all with existing apps)
I would like to use a old smartphone to simulate a beacon and leave it at home always charged just for this purpose. I would like to detect it automatically on my personal new smartphone and get a automatic notification to start a routine/automation.
Can I achieve this with already existing apps such like Beacon Scope or some other tool, on both phones, without coding?
The task looks pretty simple but I am worried about deprecated tools and old APIs and how to start automatically and manage backgroud-running apps always undertanding what is happening.
Basically I do not want to keep Wifi and/or Position always on and I would like to turn on Wifi only when I am home (i.e.: when the beacon is detected and a notification triggers my routine)
Both smartphones are Samsung Galaxy: S21 and S23
I am not able to use a existing app to fire a notification on beacon detection.

Here is what you can do:

Use an old Android phone on a charger to continually broadcast a beacon.  BeaconScope or other apps in the Play Store will work fine.l for this.

Build an Android app that performs custom  functions when the beacon is detected.  The easiest way to do this in a flexible way is to make the detector Android app send an Intent that triggers actions in other apps or the Android system.  The BeaconScope app does not support this, and I am not aware of others that do.  But you could build your own app to do this.

Send a notification on a specific beacon detection. Again, BeaconScope does not do this but you may be able to find another app that does or you could build your own.


Here is what you cannot do:

Apps cannot turn WiFi on or off as of Android 10.  You can only do this with the settings panel with a user gesture.  See: Android: How to Enable/Disable Wifi or Internet Connection Programmatically

You cannot turn location on as a result of beacon detection, because location must be on to detect beacons in the first place.  If location is off, the OS will block detection of all BLE advertisement detections or (on newer Android versions) filter out common beacon formats from BLE detections.



Thank you so much David for your answer. As I suspected the Position ON condition is a dela breaker. I will shift to bluetooth device connection as "home presence" event trigger. I just need to find a simple bluetooth device that always accepts connections without changing audio or something. Do you have any suggestion? Something like a bluetooth printer that I will use just as dummy device?

You can certainly do this with an old Android phone.  Android can act as a Bluetooth peripheral.  You might even be able to set this up with a Nordic NRF Connect utility app -- use it to create a new service and start advertising

Hi David, thank you again for your suggestion. I am trying to have NRF Connect on the older smartphone to advertise with a test advertiser but the newer phone (with bluetooth enabled) is not finding any of them. Do you have suggestions for the NRF Connect Advertiser settings? Something very dummy just for discover and connection: I do not need anything else.

After a lot of fiddling I came up with this solution.

old smartphone with a bluetooth mouse/keyboard emulator app (those to transform your phone in a wireless BT mouse for your smart tv for example)
Screen Alive app to keep it always on avoiding the block screen.
Modes&Routines app to implement a state machine connecting and disconnecting Wifi and BT every 20 seconds. I need Wifi to generate the specifi home wifi network connecting and disconnecting events to turn on and off the BT.
The mouse/kb app keeps looking for my current smartphone (previoulsy paired, of course) and accepting or cutting the BT connection according to the routines behaviour.
On my current phone I have the BT always on when travelling (and ready to connect to the car audio BT or this old smartphone when I arrive at home)
I have Routines set up to activate a Mode when the old smartphone connects on BT. This mode keeps alive just for 1 minute.
the mode activation generates an event for another routine to turn on the wifi.
only when the wifi is connected to the home network then I switch off the Bluetooth.
of corse on the wifi disconnect event I turn on the bluetooth

A lot of work that could just be avoided if Samsung had made available that single bit of Smart Tag connected/disconnected property to have Smart Things fire a notification and automate with a routine on that...
That's All Folks!
